# "Conducting" trading

Tags: word-usage

I wrote the following sentence and my teacher told me "conducting" should be replaced with "doing"

My experience in investing comes from trading options, which I have been conducting since October 2014.

Should I replace conducting with doing? Are both correct? And why?

Comment: There is a literally ‘sound’ argument against “conducting trade”.  It sounds odd because of the awkward rhyme at the end.  “Doing trading” is little better.  It depends, moreover, on context.   “Can you pop out for a moment?”  “No, I’m engaged in trading.”, or perhaps “I am busy trading.”.

Comment: @Tuffy, you mean 'conducting trading'. Juxtaposed _ing forms _are_ sometimes  awkward. I'm not happy with the use of the verbs 'conduct' and 'do' with 'trading' per se. +1 for your better suggestions, though I think they work better with OP's example than yours (where I don't think 'trading' would be mentioned).

Comment: Your teacher is correct, as you prolly would have seen if you'd done the research.
By itself “I have been conducting…” is just fine but here, the phrase is not by itself, is it?
For detailed reasons look somewhere like English Language Learners but “… trading options, which I have been conducting…” is a different case and simply does not work.